# Creating buttons for a Navigation bar

Tags: iphone, uibutton, uinavigationbar

I have a button as the right button on my navigation bar:

```
UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Add" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(addToFavouritesButtonPressed:)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;
[addButton release];
```

All good, except I'd like it to be an image of a star with a little plus on it.  Thought it would be easy to just create a png and set the UIBarButtonItem's image property.  Which it is, however 2 things.  It puts the gloss and bevel at the left and right side of my image, but not on the image itself and secondly I can't find a recommended size of button in the docs.

Is there an easy way of creating a button image and the system to format it so it looks like it is part of the Navigation Bar?  If I attempt to create the gloss and bevel in Photoshop it looks good but doesn't look quite like the system generated buttons on the left side.

Hope that makes sense and any pointers would be appreciated,

Dave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doh, didn't have an alpha channel in my png, created a mask and all looks good.